# Find Next Siblings not returning a value. How can I extract the two classes I need without the rest of the classes?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests, find

I would like to extract just the item weight and the product dimensions from "content" below. What am I missing here? In my script, the content that I am looking for is not found. Is there a simpler way to just extract item weight and product dimensions? Thanks

```
import bs4 as bs

content = '''
<th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">
Item Weight
</th>
<td class="a-size-base prodDetAttrValue">
0.16 ounces
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">
Product Dimensions
</th>
<td class="a-size-base prodDetAttrValue">
4.8 x 3.4 x 0.5 inches
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">
Batteries Included?
</th>
<td class="a-size-base prodDetAttrValue">
No
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">
Batteries Required?
</th>
<td class="a-size-base prodDetAttrValue">
No
</td>
</tr>
'''
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(content, features='lxml')


try:
    product = {
        'weight': soup.find(text='Item Weight').parent.find_next_siblings(),
        'dimension': soup.find(text='Product Dimensions').parent.find_next_siblings()
    }
except:
    product = {
        'weight': 'item unavailable',
        'dimension': 'item unavailable'
    }
print(product)
```

Traceback:

```
{'weight': 'item unavailable', 'dimension': 'item unavailable'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to find *immediate* next sibling, you need to use `.find_next_sibling()` instead of `.find_next_siblings()`. Then the reason why you are not getting any output is the representation of text inside tags. If you do:

```
print([each_th.text for each_th in soup.find_all('th')])
```

You will see that the result would look like this:

```
['\nItem Weight\n', '\nProduct Dimensions\n', '\nBatteries Included?\n', '\nBatteries Required?\n']
```

So, you need to change `text='Item Weight'` to `text='\nItem Weight\n'` and so on:

```
try:
    product = {
        'weight': soup.find(text='\nItem Weight\n').parent.find_next_sibling().text,
        'dimension': soup.find(text='\nProduct Dimensions\n').parent.find_next_sibling().text
    }
except:
    product = {
        'weight': 'item unavailable',
        'dimension': 'item unavailable'
    }
```

This will give:

```
{'weight': '\n0.16 ounces\n', 'dimension': '\n4.8 x 3.4 x 0.5 inches\n'}
```

Now if you want to remove those newline characters, you can use either `.replace('\n', '')` or `.strip()` to do it when grabbing it.

Answer (score 1):

You're using find next sibling incorrectly. The `td` tag is the sibling of the `th` tag and not of the parent `tr` tag.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

content = '''
<tr>
<th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">
Item Weight
</th>
<td class="a-size-base prodDetAttrValue">
0.16 ounces
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">
Product Dimensions
</th>
<td class="a-size-base prodDetAttrValue">
4.8 x 3.4 x 0.5 inches
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">
Batteries Included?
</th>
<td class="a-size-base prodDetAttrValue">
No
</td>
</tr>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
d = {
  'weight': soup.find('th', text=re.compile('\s*Item Weight\s*')).find_next_sibling('td').text.strip(), 
  'dimension': soup.find('th', text=re.compile('\s*Product Dimensions\s*')).find_next_sibling('td').text.strip()
  }

print(d)
```